# .htaccess to Nginx config

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to install a app I bought off of ThemeForest and I cannot get the administration center to work.

The admin folder tree looks like this

^Admin

->Lib (Folder)

->Assets (Folder)

->Src (Folder)

->More Stuff etc (Folder)

index.php (File)

The index.php file calls other files in the folders, however the browser only calls for http://url/admin/file

This makes me believe this is a url rewrite issue, however I cannot figure out how to convert this .htaccess file to Nginx

```
    Options -Indexes

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    # Index handles everything
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "_connect.php|_somesome.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: That's a pretty standard `try_files $uri /admin/index.php`

Comment: @AlexeyTen I've already tried that.